# Doctrine many to many relationship NOT IN [jointable]

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, dql

I've 2 tables with many-to-many relationship => users, roles.

I need to find all users THAT AREN'T IN ANY ROLE.

In SQL it can be done:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user`
WHERE `id` NOT
IN (
    SELECT `user_Id`
    FROM user_role
)
```

`user_role` is the joining table of many to many relationship from `user` and `role`.

How can obtain the same result with `DQL`?

**UPDATE**

The `user_role` table is an automated mapping from doctrine, if i try to use it, I get "entity not found"

Asking Better:

How can I do the same result with `CreateQueryBuilder`?

I can't be able to using the user_role table in my entity, because it's autogenerated with many-to-many relathionship annotation (or can I use it?).

Comment: `NOT IN` would become `NOT EXISTS` in `DQL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT u
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN u.roles r
WHERE r IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing should get you the required results Or you can do a join something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM user u LEFT OUTER JOIN user_role ur
ON u.id = ur.user_Id
WHERE ur.user_Id IS NULL
```